# how to merge two pandas dataframe on slightly different keys

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to merge two datasets based on the key `institution` that is differently written in both data frames. The data frames look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'institution':['Havard University', 'Oxford University', 'University of Kent', 'Harvard University']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'institution':['Havard University', 'University of Oxford', 'Kent University'], 'ranking': ['very good', 'very good', 'good']})
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please show us your expected result and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fuzzy merge.

you can check for different type of method in below links.
[fuzzy_pandas](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzy-pandas/),
[different types of string similarity algorithms](https://itnext.io/string-similarity-the-basic-know-your-algorithms-guide-3de3d7346227)

```
import fuzzy_pandas as fpd
merged_df=fpd.fuzzy_merge(df1, df2, left_on=['name'],right_on=['name'],method='jaro', ignore_case=True,threshold=0.9)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it does not work with the large data set. I get this error:

`6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/csvmatch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     66 
     67 def process_ignore_case(row):
---> 68     return [value.lower() for value in row]
     69 
     70 def process_ignore_nonalpha(row):

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: ohh! this error is because you need to replace the NA value with empty string in the columns on which merge is happening

Comment: Thanks! Another issue: there is no longer an error, but somehow fuzzy pandas stops after ca. 25% of the sample. Institutions that have already been detected are no longer merged. Any idea why?

Comment: I didn't get the issue. can you please explain?

Comment: I had to reset the index, then it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping function:

```
mapping = {'Havard University':'Harvard University','Oxford University':'University of Oxford','University of Kent':'Kent University','Harvard University':'Harvard University'}

df1['institution'] = df1.institution.map(mapping)
df1.merge(df2,on='institution',how='left')
```

#### Output:

```
            institution    ranking
0    Harvard University        NaN
1  University of Oxford  very good
2       Kent University       good
3    Harvard University        NaN
```